# How to resolve a non-numeric argument to binary operator error when I try to apply an entropy calculation?

Tags: r, entropy

I get an error when I try to apply an entropy calculation to my data.
Here's a example that works with sample data:

```
#Non-uniform entropy-esque measure
   

#Example Data
id <- c(0,2,3,4,5,6,7)
Region_ID <- c(0,2,2,3,0,3,2)
BaseunitPOP <- c(10000,4000,8000,8000,10000,11000,13000)
RegionPOP<- c(20000,25000,25000,19000,20000,19000,25000)

S.data <- data.frame(id, Region_ID, BaseunitPOP,RegionPOP)

       
#For each region, calculate non-uniform entropy-type measure
#Or skip to the bottom of script to calculate for ALL regions at once

#region 1
#-(10000*log((10000/20000),2)+(10000*log((10000/20000),2)))

#region 2
#-(4000*log((4000/25000),2)+(8000*log((8000/25000),2))+(13000*log((13000/25000)))

#region 3
#...

######################
#For ALL Regions

S.data %>% group_by(Region_ID) %>%
  summarise(result=-sum(BaseunitPOP*log((BaseunitPOP/RegionPOP),2)))
```

When I try to apply this to my data (use the code below to call on a sample of my data):

```
structure(list(region_ID = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), TOTPOP_CY = c(1286, 
    995, 838, 628, 719, 974), `sum(TOTPOP_CY)` = c(22644, 22644, 
    22644, 22644, 22644, 22644)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

apply to my data with this code:

```
Entropy= EntropyJoin%>% group_by(region_ID) %>%
           summarise(result=-sum(TOTPOP_CY*log((TOTPOP_CY/"sum(TOTPOP_CY)"),2)))
```

I get an error:

```
Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `result`.
x non-numeric argument to binary operator
i Input `result` is `-sum(TOTPOP_CY * log((TOTPOP_CY/"sum(TOTPOP_CY)"), 2))`.
i The error occurred in group 1: region_ID = 0.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not name your column in the previous step. You probably had something like :

```
.... %>% mutate(sum(TOTPOP_CY))
```

You should instead correct it to :

```
.... %>% mutate(sum_TOTPOP = sum(TOTPOP_CY))
```

Then  you can use :

```
Entropy = EntropyJoin%>% 
           group_by(region_ID) %>%
           summarise(result=-sum(TOTPOP_CY*log((TOTPOP_CY/sum_TOTPOP),2)))
```

---

Nonetheless, if you don't want to go and change your previous step you can refer to variable name with a backtick (`) here.

```
EntropyJoin %>% 
  group_by(region_ID) %>%
  summarise(result=-sum(TOTPOP_CY*log((TOTPOP_CY/`sum(TOTPOP_CY)`),2)))
```